# Google map WatchPosition doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to implement a functionality where I need to keep track of the user position, in first, I retrieve the location of the user using getCurrentLocation then I pass the coordinates to place a marker indicating the user location (the marker variable is set globally), then I call the watchPosition function so it can keep track of the user location if its location has been changed.
This code is implemented for an Ionic app, but the same logic will be used on any web application (you can ignore $cordovaGeolocation since it's the same as  navigator.geolocation)

```
var map = null;
var myPosition = null;

$scope.initMap = function(){
    var posOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 20000,         
    };

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(
        function (position) {
            var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);               
            $scope.me = myLatlng;

            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 11,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

            };          

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions); 

            myPosition = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: myLatlng,
                draggable:false,
                icon: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/orZ4x.png",
            });             
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({radius: User.getUser().distance*1000, center: myLatlng}); 
            map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());              
            $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(win);
        },
        function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
}
```

the callback for the watchPosition function is below:

```
var win = function(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    if(myPosition==null){
        myPosition = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: myLatlng,
            draggable:false,
            icon: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/orZ4x.png",
        });
        myPosition.setMap(map);
    }else{
        myPosition.setPosition(myLatlng);
    }
    map.panTo(myLatlng);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the error here was something with $cordovaGeolocation, replacing it with navigator.geolocation solved the issue for me.